# WMQ Pub/Sub Topic to Queue bridge

Tags: ibm-mq

In other queue managers it is possible to setup a bridge between a queue to a topic so that publishers and subscribers does not need to know that they are using a topic:

Example in [TIBCO EMS](http://www.tibco.com/products/soa/messaging/enterprise-mesage-service/default.jsp)

> create Bridge source=queue:QName
>   target=topic:TName
>   create Bridge
>   source=topic:TName target=queue:QName

How do I do this in WMQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See WebSphere [MQ V7.0 Features and Enhancements](http://publib-b.boulder.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247583.html?Open) page 47, it mentions the use of Alias queues and administrative subscriptions

> WebSphere MQ V7.0 introduces an
>   extension to the alias queue object
>   that allows it to be resolved to the
>   new topic object. This is useful for
>   migrating point-to-point messaging
>   applications to the Publish/Subscribe
>   model. A traditional point-to-point
>   application that puts messages into
>   WebSphere MQ can operate as a
>   publisher without any code changes by
>   utilizing an alias queue that resolves
>   to a topic object. This is implemented
>   administratively by defining a topic
>   object that maps to an appropriate
>   topic string on which the messages are
>   to be published. The original local
>   queue is deleted and replaced by an
>   alias queue of the same name that
>   resolves to the topic object. Also
>   note that a point-to-point application
>   that gets messages from WebSphere MQ
>   can operate as a subscriber without
>   any code changes by defining an
>   administrative subscription to a
>   topic.

Example 9.3 on page 220 shows how to setup a administrative subscription from a Topic to a destination queue

```
DEFINE SUB(SUB.RETAIL.CAT) TOPICOBJ(MATT.RETAIL.CAT) DESTCLAS(MANAGED)
DEFINE SUB(SUB.MATTRETCAT) TOPICSTR(‘matt/retail/cat’) DESTCLAS(MANAGED)
DEFINE SUB(SUB.PROVCAT) TOPICSTR(‘matt/retail/cat’) DEST(SUB.PROVCAT.DESTQ)
```

Comment: The only gotcha with this method is that WMQ topics will not accept grouped messages.  The reason for this is that you don't know whether a subscription will be made in the middle of a group.  If that happened the subscriber would have half a group and no way to get the first message(s).  I'm not sure how other transports handle this but it would take a lot of server-side code to cache messages for replay for this and would degrade performance so I suspect disallowing grouped messages would be a common approach.

Comment: Thanks T.Rob. Do you know of any further limitations on Z?

Comment: When you say "further", did you interpret my comment to apply specifically to Z?  Because message groups are a feature of WMQ on all current platforms, as is the ability to alias topics and queues.  No Z-specific limitations come to mind for any of this functionality.