# Can a queue consume from a topic directly in a publish-subscribe mode

Tags: mule

Can a queue consume from a topic directly in a publish-subscribe mode.Can somebody provide pointers on this. I am using websphere MQ as a JMS broker.What should be the Mule configuration for setting this up.

***Mule Configuration***

testTopic10 is the topic name
testQueue10 is the queue name

```
<!-- Publisher Flow -->
<flow name="PublisherFlow" doc:name="PublisherFlow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="c:\retryin" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint topic="testTopic10" doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="WMQ_Pub_Topic_Connector"/>
</flow>

<!-- Transfer from topic to Queue -->
<flow name="SubscriberFlowQueueTransfer" doc:name="SubscriberFlowQueueTransfer">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint topic="testTopic10" connector-ref="WMQ_Pub_Topic_Connector" doc:name="JMS">
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger message="Entered Subscriber Queue transfer" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="testQueue10" connector-ref="WMQ_Sub_Queue_Connector" doc:name="JMS">
    </jms:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>

<!-- Subscriber Flow -->

<flow name="SubscriberFlowQueue" doc:name="SubscriberFlowQueue">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="testQueue10" connector-ref="WMQ_Sub_Queue_Connector" doc:name="JMS">
        <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" timeout="3000"/> 
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger message="Entered subscriber flow" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <ftp:outbound-endpoint host="XXX.XXX.XX.XX" port="21" path="path" user="test" password="test123" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP"/>
    <rollback-exception-strategy  doc:name="Rollback Exception Strategy" enableNotifications="false"/>
</flow>
```

***Connector Configurations***

```
<jms:connector  name="WMQ_Pub_Topic_Connector" specification="1.1" validateConnections="true" connectionFactory-ref="WebSphereMQConnectionFactory" doc:name="JMS" durable="true" clientId="mule-server-01" persistentDelivery="true" maxRedelivery="5">
     <reconnect-forever frequency="5000" />
</jms:connector>
<jms:connector name="WMQ_Sub_Queue_Connector" specification="1.1" validateConnections="true" connectionFactory-ref="WebSphereMQConnectionFactory" doc:name="JMS" durable="true" clientId="mule-server-01" persistentDelivery="true" maxRedelivery="5">
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1"/>   
    <reconnect-forever/>
</jms:connector>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward, you can take a look at [WebSphere MQ transpor documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+WMQ+Transport+Reference) and [WebShphere MQ example](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/WebSphere+MQ+Example). But basically you need to:

1. Configure a WMQ connector

   ```
   <wmq:connector name="wmqConnector" hostName="${wmq.host}" port="${wmq.port}" queueManager="${wmq.queue.manager}" username="${wmq.username}" password="${wmq.password}" />
   ```
2. Create a flow with an endpoint

   ```
   <flow name="MessageProcessor">
       <wmq:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="wmqConnector" queue="topic.in">
       ...
   </flow>
   ```
3. Add MQ jars to MULE_HOME/lib/user

   - com.ibm.mq.jar
   - com.ibm.mqetclient.jar (if using remote XA transactions)
   - com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
   - com.ibm.mqjms.jar
   - dhbcore.jar

Comment: I was not able to explain properly. The publisher sends messages to a messaging topic. The subscriber is a messaging queue that directly consumes from a topic. I have modified my earlier question adding the mule configuration.

Comment: I am able to achieve this adding a configuration  "Transfer from topic to Queue" please refer the configuration above. Can the queue directly consume from the topic without this step

Comment: Can't you put the messages in the first flow directly to the topic? Would an alias work? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666467/wmq-pub-sub-topic-to-queue-bridge) Would a bridge work? (href="http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ledoc/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rcp.tools.doc.servermqe/cfg61180.html)